# What would you recommend for Voice Dictation in Linux?

Tags: debian, software-rec, text-to-speech

Ok, so I'm looking for a simple live-dictation tool that will run natively in linux, not a web-based app.

For context, I've looked around on Google, Checked out other SE posts asking the same thing in more vague ways, asked ChatGPT, Nosed around on GitHub, and so on so forth.

Between them, the above have recommended a variety of tools, including vosk, sphinx, transcriber, and a number of others. None of them have been very successful for me.

I have tried using dictation in the cloud-based version of MS Word. That was successful but I'd prefer a non-cloud-based toool

The Distro I want to implement this on is Debian.

Does anyone have any suggestions of alternative tools/packages I could try?

UPDATE:
This answer has been most helpful:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/772356/537545

I've got SpeechNote set up and working thanks to the instructions provided by Marcus Müller, to whom I'm very grateful.

I'm going to test out the numerous English Language Models available within SpeechNote, and will add an additional update at some point regarding which one seems to be most optimal in terms of speed, accuracy and lack of interjection of automated junk ("thanks for using this software" sort of insertions)

In the meantime, if people have any additional software suggestions, please don't hesitate to add further contributions.

Thank you all :)

Comment: does your debian system have a GPU that support PyTorch? And: am I right to assume this is about English texts only?

Comment: It is about english text, but if there's a tool that requires configuration, that's fine.

With regards to PyTorch, I'll take a look and see if it's any good for my use case. Further suggestions would be welcome :)

Comment: PyTorch itself is just the DNN/Machine Learning platform much of modern speech recognition neural networks are based on. It's not useful in itself. You both need a neural network that's been trained to "understand" English, and some software frontend. But if you don't have a GPU compatible with it, we don't need to investigate that direction any further, which is why I ask.

Comment: Well the computer I'm using is an old Toughbook that Ive had for a few years. Chances are the GPU isn't compatible.

Comment: There's literally **nothing decent** for Linux. You could use websites instead. Such tools cost massively to develop and the Linux market is just too small for companies to get interested in it.

Comment: Had a look at some web-based stuff. I did specify in the post that I'm not after a web-based app.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm not so sure there's nothing decent. Just because you don't know it… That being said, my definition of "decent" is a ca 2005 philips program, so, it really depends on what you mean with "decent". All the state-of-the art speech recognition development happens on Linux machines, though, so I'm pretty optimistic that if *anything* is decent in transcription quality, it runs on linux. The question is what the frontend is.

Comment: I guess it's just a case of "fingers crossed" on that front.

Comment: To the OP: Dragon Naturally Speaking 12.5 kinda sorta works in Wine: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28034

Comment: I haven't heard mention of Dragon Naturally Speaking since the '90s. We had that on disk back when I was a kid and chunky monitors were commonplace :D

Comment: I hate whataboutisms, nothing is going on with me. I'm just trying to be honest and rational. Linux on servers and AI systems running on Linux are **completely** orthogonal to the question. Those systems like you said need a frontend. The way they are created they are unusable for the OP. You won't recommend the OP to come to e.g. Google and open up their server fleet with very raw APIs if any to use voice dictation. And it doesn't matter what you remember about Dragon Naturally Speaking. It is still excellent at least for native English speakers.

Comment: In my experience https://voicenotebook.com/ is the best free option bar none if you're not averse to using the Internet. Its precision is staggering. I've not seen anything close in terms of being correct most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [Speech Note](https://github.com/mkiol/dsnote); I use it sometimes for when I take notes while assembling things and thus have limited free hands.

I've got a very noticeable German accent, but it performs well enough for most English that I speak. It doesn't do things like "type directly into my word processor", but I don't think that's strictly a requirement, as far as your question is concerned?

What Speech Note is, is a frontend to a couple of speech model Neural Networks; it's not got the latest and greatest, but Whisper is honestly quite OK for English. As mentioned in the comments, most work on speech recognition is done on desktop machines running Linux.

I've [installed it from Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/net.mkiol.SpeechNote); since your laptop doesn't have a GPU that could do the inference faster and at lower power consumption than your CPU, there's no point in installing any accelerator plugins. So, to get running, on debian, you'd need to set up flatpak, then install the Speech Note program, then run that, and select an appropriate English model.

I haven't tested this on debian, but coming from the flatpack documentation, this should work:

```bash
# Check whether flatpak is installed, and install it if not
flatpak --help > /dev/null || sudo apt install flatpak -y
# end of debian-specific instructions.

# Set up the flatpak software repo
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

# Install Speech Note in container environment
flatpak install net.mkiol.SpeechNote
```

I don't know whether that is sufficient for debian to have menu entries for SpeechNote; anyways, you can launch it directly

```bash
flatpak run net.mkiol.SpeechNote
```

Now, click on the "Languages" Button, and in there "English". From "Speech to Text" select "English (FasterWhisper Small)/en", by clicking on its download button. Wait till Download finishes. Close the dialog; go into the top-left burger menu [image: hamburger menu icon] icon, go to "Settings", go to "Speech to Text", and select the correct Audio Source. Close the dialog.

You're ready to go – Hit the "Listen" button and be a benevolent dictator!

EDIT: [Here's it in action](https://imgur.com/a/upJ1nlH) (make sure to unmute the video)

[image: video]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I've installed this and am currently experimenting with the various language packages available to find which one is most accurate based on my voice. It's mostly accurate in general, but my voice isn't the most optimal. "Gruff" would be the word I'd use to describe my voice :D:D

Comment: I found FasterWhisper Small being pretty accurate, but still manageable to run on a CPU; but yeah, it's probably a tradeoff

Comment: Yep, that was the first one installed, as per the suggestion. Works quite well. The one problem I have is the occasional insertion of "thank you", "thanks for listening" etc.

Comment: you sound like a polite person :)

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. Polite and civil are my main preferences. I tend to save rude for the people who instigate disrespect, but even in those situations, it's more of a "backup" used for people who won't listen to reason...

Comment: English (distil-whisper medium) is taking a long time to process but is definitely the most accurate at this time. I'd strongly recommend that one if you have some patience.

Comment: Thanks! I really do need to get my GPU drivers to cooperate.

Comment: No problem. Hopefully your Drivers behave themselves soon :D

Comment: I'm gonna test out the speed and accuracy of all of the English Language Models. I've no idea how long that will take, but sooner or later I'll pop my final opinion into an edit on my original question. When that edit will occur depends on numerous factors, one of which is a dreadful memory, so I can't give any specific date/time, it's just a question of "watch this space" :D